# How to access grammar from query builder?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I'm trying to convert a json column name with path 'foo->bar' to be compatible with mysql/postgresql using Laravel's [wrapJsonSelector()](https://laravel.com/api/7.x/Illuminate/Database/Query/Grammars/Grammar.html#method_wrapJsonSelector) method.

How can I access this method from the query builder calling getGrammar throws error:

> Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\MySqlGrammar::isJsonSelector does not exist.

Eg

```php
$query->where(function (Builder $query) use ($searchColumn): Builder {
    if ($query->getGrammar()->isJsonSelector($searchColumn)) {
        $searchColumn = $query->getGrammar()->wrapJsonSelector($searchColumn);
    }
    // ...
})
```

Comment: *"How can I access this method"* It's protected, so you can't.

Comment: Gosh I hadn't realised that usually get a different error. Is there a way of opening it up via a macro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`isJsonSelector` and `wrapJsonSelector` are protected methods, which means you cannot access them from outside the class.  However, you don’t need to invoke either of them directly in the first place.  You can just use the `wrap` method, which [will invoke `wrapJsonSelector` in the case you want to cover here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/88dd075b9f1beaff93796a0ee51818796ca04654/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Grammars/Grammar.php#L1149-L1154).

Answer (score 1):

The `wrapJsonSelector` method is not accessible (protected), but it is called in the `wrap` method.

```
$expression = $query->getGrammar()->wrap("table.column->?"); // "table"."column"->>'?'
$query->whereRaw($expression, ['value']);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DB::table('your_table')
->selectRaw('your_json_column->"$.foo->bar" as modified_column')
->get();
```

The selectRaw method allows you to write raw SQL expressions within your query.

Comment: Not looking to do this manually due to needing to support MySQL and Postgresql reason for wanting to access `wrapJsonSelector` where Laravel handles json_unquote & json_extract